# Позиционное форматирование строки

Tags: c++, linux, g++, c++11, printf

На данный момент вывожу аргументы так: `("Name=%s Lastname=%s",name,lastname);`

Хочу сделать так, чтоб можно было так: `("Name=%1 Lastname=%2",name,lastname);`

Как это возможно реализовать в C++?

Comment: You can do a similar output in C++/CLI like WriteLine( "Name={0} Lastname={1}", name, lastname ); :)

Comment: Есть возможность использовать сторонние библиотеки, например Boost?

Comment: я использую snprintf, желательно без Boost, про boost Format наслышан уже

Comment: Что значит "как это возможно реализовать в C++"? Сесть и реализовать - только так. Или под "реализовать" имеется в виду "найти готовое"?

Comment: Непонятно, причем тут C++, если речь идет про `printf`

Answer (score 1):

Если в проекте не используется `boost`, то я бы рекомендовал посмотреть в сторону [C++ Format](https://github.com/cppformat/cppformat). Библиотека добавляется в проект, добавлением всего двух файлов. И, судя по тестам, она весьма шустрая. Писать подобное самому не стоит, готовых решений предостаточно, а написание подобное библиотеки может оказаться не самой тривиальной задачей.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартными средствами никак нельзя, но зато такое умеют сторонние библиотеки. Из общеупотребимого, например, как вам подсказывали, [boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/format/doc/format.html). Или класс QString из Qt с его методом [arg](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg). Но ради только этого, Qt ставить слишком жирно конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Никак: среда выполнения должна знать тип переданной переменной, и так или иначе вы должны его ей сообщить. Если уж очень хочется, напишите свой вариант `printf` - что-то вроде такого:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h> // M_PI

typedef struct printpos_item_s {
    union {
        double f;
        int d;
        char *s;
    };
    char type;
} printpos_item_s;

#define PITEM(t, v) (printpos_item_s) { \
    .type = #t [0], \
    .t = (v) \
}

#define printpos(format, ...) \
    printpos_a(format, (printpos_item_s[]){ __VA_ARGS__ })

void printpos_a(const char *format, printpos_item_s args[]) {
    char *f = NULL;
    char *cur, *last;

    f = strdup(format); // чтобы можно было править
    cur = f;
    do {
        last = strsep(&cur, "%");
        printf("%s", last);
        if (!cur) {
            break; // конец строки
        }
        if (cur[0] == '%') {
            putchar('%');
            cur++;
        } else {
            long pos = strtol(cur, &cur, 10);
            switch (args[pos].type) {
            case 's':
                printf("%s", args[pos].s);
                break;
            case 'f':
                printf("%f", args[pos].f);
                break;
            case 'd':
                printf("%d", args[pos].d);
                break;
            default:
                abort();
            }
        }
    } while(last);

    free(f);
}

int main() {
    printpos(
        "%0, %1, %%, %0, %2\n",
        PITEM(d, 1234),
        PITEM(s, "hello"),
        PITEM(f, M_PI)
    );
}
```

Только этот код не production ready и требует поддержки фич C99 (то есть компилятор MSVC это не примет) - но это все можно поправить, если нужно. А так обычного `printf` вам хватит для любых нужд.

Answer (score -1):

С помощью `printf()` - нельзя. `%s`, `%f` и т.д - это спецификаторы.
А то, что Вам нужно называется поля форматирования (`format fields`), пример на Rust:

```
println!("{0} форматирования.", "Поля");
```

Как использовать что-то подобное в C++ я, увы, не знаю.
Подробнее про `printf()` - [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: Не является ответом, поскольку Вы не описали, как данный функционал может быть реализован на языке C++.

Comment: Согласен с Вами, но на момент написания ответа не мог прокомментировать вопрос - не хватало репутации.